# how to download a file from server using static webpage?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, jqgrid

I'm using a static web page. When I click a button I want to download a file from the web browser. I'm using `json`, `jquery`, and `jqgrid`. Can you tell how to download using `json`, `jquery`, and `jqgrid`?

Here is my code:

```
string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myFilePath"].ToString();
Guid g;
g = Guid.NewGuid();
string strFilename = EmpId + g + ".xml";
string Mappingpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath + strFilename);
xmlDoc.Save(Mappingpath);
return filePath + strFilename;
```

and my `jqgrid` code is

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "EmployeeDetails.aspx/savefile_XML",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{'getdata':" + JSON.stringify(getdata) + "}",
    success: function (msg) {
        window.open(msg.d, "Employyees");
        var link = document.createElement("EmployeeDetails");
        var fileName = data.substring(data.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        link.download = fileName;
        link.href = data;
        link.click();
        alert("downloaded");
    },
```

In that code windows.open() works fine, but my file is not downloaded from the web browser. I got an error in Internet Explorer; it is JavaScript run-time error: `Object doesn't support property or method lastIndexOf`.

My question is how to use this code to download a file when the user clicks the button to show the save file location window.

Comment: Hi Hope this helps  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609442/Using-JqGrid-in-ASP-NET

Comment: thanks for replay..but iam asking when i click row that row details downloaded  in webbrowser ....

Comment: Im curious if your data variable is null\undefined.  Can you put a console.log in your script and check what the value of "data" is?  Also, run Fiddler\Browser Developer Tools and watch the network calls when you run this script, do you get a 404\500 HTTP code back from the JSON call?  Or do you get a 200?

Comment: you specify the data type as json.   A json object wont support lastIndexOf

Comment: then which code i write ..plz suggest me .. i tried lot of codes ..

Comment: i  uses window.open(...)  when click download it  open file .but i dont want ..i want show pop ...download which drive we want..or download in web browser

Comment: how Download File from C# through  Web Method via Ajax call?.......any one tell example ......i search lots of codes .....but no use ...how can i over come my problem..